# Finding the largest square divisor of a number

Tags: number-theory

My calculator has the option of representing square roots in the form of $a\sqrt b$, when $a$ is maximal. 
It works for very large inputs within seconds, and I wonder how it's being done.

Comment: What are "very large inputs"? Ten digits, twenty, hundred?

Comment: About 15 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculator finds the prime factorisation of $x$, then factors out every term with prime exponent 2. For example, $720=2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$, so $\sqrt{720}=12\sqrt{5}$.

If you are wondering how it does that so fast, well, that is just because it can execute a lot of calculations in a short time.

Comment: Thanks. Which algorithm is being used to factorize numbers with about 16 digits?

Comment: @nanush The best way to factor the 16 digit number is using Pollard Rho.Also this can be solve with trial division with prime numbers only in n^1/3 maximum operation .But with Pollard Rho  it will become easy. There is a similar problem available on spoj http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/HOMEW/  for which my Pollarh rho takes 0.16s(there are around one thousand test case with at most 18 digit).

Answer (score 1):

As imple algorithm such as the following may be suitable for not too large positive integer inputs $n$:

1. Let $a\leftarrow 1$, $b\leftarrow 1$
2. While $4\mid n$, let $a\leftarrow 2a$ and $n\leftarrow n/4$
3. If $2\mid n$, let $b\leftarrow 2b$ and $n\leftarrow n/2$
4. Let $p=3$
5. While $p^2\mid n$, let $a\leftarrow pa$, $n\leftarrow n/p^2$
6. If $n<p^2$, let $b\leftarrow n$ and terminate with the answer: $a\cdot \sqrt b$
7. If $p\mid b$, let $b\leftarrow pb$ and $n\leftarrow n/p$.
8. Let $p\leftarrow p+2$ and go back to step 5

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the largest number you can use is not TOO big, e.g. your calculator should have no problem if your starting numbers are around 16-20 digits or less. If you are allowed to use larger numbers, try taking the product of two large primes (say, around 30 digits each) whose number of digits differ by around 8 or so. That should almost certainly screw up your calculator.

Anyway, if all you care about is finding square divisors that you can factor out, then for example for a 20 digit number you only have look for factors up to 10 digits long, and using Pollard rho the expected time to get the prime factorization for a composite number is more like $10^5$ (the fourth root of your original number) arithmetic operations rather than $10^{10}$. And after a while the Pollard rho can be used to say a number is "probably prime". So it's possible your calculator might even be able to handle 30-35 digit numbers.