# Partial square root of an integer

Tags: algorithms, square-numbers

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to compute what I'd call the "partial square root" of an integer. In more formal terms:

Given a positive integer $k$, find the pair of positive integers $(r,n)$ with the smallest $n$ such that $k=r^2n$.

Naively, one could start with $(r,n)=(1,k)$, iterate over all $p \in \{2,3,5,7,...,2i+1\}$ (as a stand-in for all the primes), and while $n/p^2$ is integer, compute $(r',n')=(rp,n/p^2)$, but something tells me that there should be a more more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375665/finding-the-largest-square-divisor-of-a-number).

Comment: Efficiency will depend on the size of $k$ and the cost of coding compared to execution.  In some cases it may not even be worth finding primes rather than integers (or odd integers), and clearly you can stop when $p^4 > n'$

Comment: To me, a clearer way to word this question is, "what is the largest square number which divides into $k$?"

Comment: No, that's not the same question. What your question is asking for is $r^2$, while I'm specifically asking for $r$.
If the question were, "name _any_ alhorithm that can do X", then it wouldn't make much of a difference, since any solution to one question could be easily transformed into a solution to the other. But the added constraint of efficiency _may_ make a difference between the two. Unlikely, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish the task is to factor $k=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ where $p_i$ are primes that divide $k$.

Then, for each instance in which an exponent $a_i$ is odd, call them $a_j$, use the corresponding prime base to form the product $n=\prod p_j$.

The quotient $\frac{k}{n}$ will then have only prime factors with even exponents, and hence will be a square, $r^2$.

You cannot make $n$ smaller by removing one or more of the $p_j$ from its definition, as that will leave one or more of the remaining $p_i$ in $\frac{k}{n}$ with an odd exponent, and that cannot be a square.